# Print User Digits and Recordings from Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have successfully created a flow in Twilio Studio to prompt a caller to enter some Digits and record a voice message. Ideally, I would like to be able to use PHP to echo the Digits and the voice recording so I can click and play the message based on the Digits. I do not see any documentation for such a project. Is there a better way of doing this? Should I not be using Studio? Using the Twilio API, the following code allows me to view each recording and click to hear the individual recording:

```
require_once 'Twilio/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "AC#######";
$token  = "#########";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);  

$recordings = $twilio->recordings
                     ->read();

foreach ($recordings as $record) {
    print('<a href="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC######/
                    Recordings/'.$record->sid.'".wav?Download=false">play</a><br>');
}
```

I tried appending for each like this to no success. Noting echoed:

```
foreach ($recordings as $record) {
$digits = simplexml_load_string($_REQUEST['Digits']);
echo $digits;
```

How can I echo the Digits the user entered to the left of each recording?